# CardView is not filled up completely by the RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-cardview

**Empty Space left behind even after fill_parent .. Is this a cardView bug or Me doing something wrong.. Any Help appreciated..Thanks..Commented part is to be toggled on TextView labeled "Select" press.This is sufficient information and enough details.Any help would be appreciated**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="22.5"
            android:background="@color/blue">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_select"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="49.8"
                    android:background="@color/blue"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="No,Thanks"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:background="#ffffff" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_select"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="49.8"
                    android:background="@color/blue"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Select"

                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

           <!-- <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_unselect"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_unselect"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#b6b6b6"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Unselect"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>
    -->

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using CardView as main parent node try nesting it inside LinearLayout

Comment: Can you put a screenshot  ?

Comment: No credits to put up Image.. Thanks anyways.. Found a way..  setPreventCornerOverlap(false) did the trick